# Magento 1 :: Having URL that shows "New" product

Tags: java, php, magento

I have a list of "Deal of the Day" products that will go up one at a time on different days. There will only be 1 Deal of the Day product Live at a time.

4059_ April 3

4061_ April 4

I am wondering if it is possible to use the "Set Product as New from Date" and "Set Product as New to Date" attributes to show each product on the same url example: www.mywebsite.com/deal-of-the-day - this would be a Product Display Page (PDP)

When a products Date to be set as "New" comes around, then the product will automatically show up in the example url.

Example:
On April 3, product SKU 4059_ will appear on at the URL www.mywebsite.com/deal-of-the-day.
On April 4, the product 4059_ will no longer be at that URL and the next product 4061_ will appear.

Is this even something that is possible to do? any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What relations does this have to amp-html?

Comment: i have no idea why that was there. Removed.